# What's the cleanest way to bind enumerated properties?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings, binding, nsmenu, nsmenuitem

I have a menu which has an item for each value in an enum.

The menu:

```
[ ] Sort by Due Date
[ ] Sort by Priority
[√] Sort by Title
```

The enum:

```
typedef enum  CW_TASK_SORT_METHOD {
    CWTaskSortMethodDueDate,
    CWTaskSortMethodPriority,
    CWTaskSortMethodTitle
} CWTaskSortMethod;
```

The property:

```
@property(readwrite, assign) CWTaskSortMethod taskSortMethod;
```

What's the cleanest way to wire this up? I have two ideas but both strike me as unsatisfactory.

1st idea: Create properties for each value (`sortMethodIsDueDate`, `setSortMethodIsDueDate:` etc) These properties would call `setTaskSortMethod:` and call `valueDidChange:@"sortMethodIsDueDate"` etc. The menu items would then bind to these properties. This seems like a lot of work.

2nd idea: Connect each menu item to `-(IBAction)updateSortMethod:(id)sender` which could then iterate the menu items and set the value depending on `sender`. This approach is fine until `taskSortMethod` is changed by a different section of code at which point code needs to be added to keep the menu in sync with `taskSortMethod`.

I'm leaning towards the first approach as it has better separation between the V & C.

Any better ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're on the right track with your second idea, but there's something to consider:

NSMenu / NSMenuItem don't have a concept of "selected item" like NSPopUpButton for instance. I'd use the target/action mechanism to change the sort method and menu validation ([Introduction to User Interface Validation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UIValidation/UIValidation.html)) or even the NSMenu delegate method -menu:updateItem:atIndex:shouldCancel: ([NSMenuDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSMenuDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)) to update the state of the item based on the result of -taskSortMethod.

Since the menu items only need to be updated when they're shown (which this mechanism does for you), you don't have to worry about updating the menu items yourself when -taskSortMethod changes elsewhere.

Ex:

```
[sortByDueDateMenuItem setState: ([self taskSortMethod] == CWTaskSortMethodDueDate) ];
```

IMO, this is a lot cleaner than trying to over-engineer a bindings-powered solution.

Comment: I've gone with the 2nd approach. I think the next time this problem comes up I'll create a class to address it. I'm surprised there isn't a more elegant solution.